Laravel Backpack CRUD Update View is Loading Incorrect Entry
I am experiencing a weird issue with Laravel Backpack (v5). I have a Template Model that I added the Clone Operation to. This is the only model in my project that currently has Clone capabilities. The weird thing is that when I try and edit any of my entries (cloned or not), they do not pay attention to the $id/$key in the URL/route and instead load the lowest $id in the DB associated to that user.
I've never seen this before. Any help would be much appreciated.
I have inspected the entry that loads and can see the id is not matching. The weird thing is that request()->route('id') shows the correct ID but $this->crud->getCurrentEntry() does not. I was expecting that the UpdateOperation would always use the id in the route.

Share your code and point out what is not working ?

When I load a URL like: /admin/template/32/edit, I would expect the entry that I am editing to be the one with an id of 32 in this model. However the view loads with data from a different entry. The model does this for all the entries I have access to from this user. The code for updateOperation just points you to the createOperation, as the default is in backpack:
  protected function setupUpdateOperation()     {         $this->setupCreateOperation();     } It is happening outside of the CRUD and Model I suspect. Maybe in the Middleware, but I am not sure.

This has not happened in any of my other models, only difference being that this one includes a Clone Operation

When I try to catch the getCurrentEntry() as soon as the createOperation loads, I can see it's the incorrect entry loaded

Does removing the CloneOperation fix you issue ?

No unfortunately it doesn't :/

I figured it out. I had an orWhere clause in the Setup function that was throwing it off. When I put that in the setupCreateOperation function instead everything functioned as expected.

After debugging for a while, it came down to an orWhere clause I had in the Setup function in the controller.
When I moved that same clause into the setupCreateOperation function everything functioned as expected.
